# Set value of input to nothing after Option change with Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

There are a lot of questions about something similar to this but they dont seem to work. 
I have a select field with 3 values - DVD/BOOK/FURNITURE

```
<select name="productType" id="productType">
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose type</option>
                <option id="dvd" value="dvd">DVD</option>
                <option id="book" value="book">Book</option>
                <option id="furniture" value="furniture">Furniture</option>
            </select>
```

And depending on which one you choose extra input fields are displayed using JQuery with this code right here:

```
$(function () {
  $("#productType").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val === "dvd") {
        $(".dvd").show();
        $(".book").hide();
        $(".furniture").hide();
    }
    else if(val === "book") {
        $(".book").show();
        $(".dvd").hide();
        $(".furniture").hide();
    }
    else if(val === "furniture") {
        $(".furniture").show();
        $(".dvd").hide();
        $(".book").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Those input fields are written like this:

```
            <div class="dvd" hidden>
                <label for="size">Size (MB)</label>
                <input type="text" name="size" id="size">
            </div>
            <div class="book" hidden>
                <label for="weight">Weight (KG)</label>
                <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight">
            </div>
            <div class="furniture" hidden>
                <label for="height">Height</label>
                <input type="text" name="height" id="height"><br>
                <label for="width">Width</label>
                <input type="text" name="width" id="width"><br>
                <label for="length">Length</label>
                <input type="text" name="length" id="length"><br>
            </div>
```

Problem right now is e.g - If I write something in the first input which is Size
And then change it to Furniture and change it back to Size the value I wrote is still there.
I want the value to disappear after I switch to one of the other inputs.

So far I've tried it with this code but it doesn't work:

```
$(function () {
  $("#productType").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val === "dvd") {
        $(".dvd").show();
        $(".book").hide();
        $(".furniture").hide();

        **$("#weight").val("");
        $("#height").val("");
        $("#width").val("");
        $("#length").val("");**

    }
    else if(val === "book") {
        $(".book").show();
        $(".dvd").hide();
        $(".furniture").hide();
    }
    else if(val === "furniture") {
        $(".furniture").show();
        $(".dvd").hide();
        $(".book").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('input').val('')` to reset the value of all inputs.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#productType").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('input').val('');
    if (val === "dvd") {
      $(".dvd").show();
      $(".book").hide();
      $(".furniture").hide();
    } else if (val === "book") {
      $(".book").show();
      $(".dvd").hide();
      $(".furniture").hide();
    } else if (val === "furniture") {
      $(".furniture").show();
      $(".dvd").hide();
      $(".book").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="productType" id="productType">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose type</option>
  <option id="dvd" value="dvd">DVD</option>
  <option id="book" value="book">Book</option>
  <option id="furniture" value="furniture">Furniture</option>
</select>

<div class="dvd" hidden>
  <label for="size">Size (MB)</label>
  <input type="text" name="size" id="size">
</div>
<div class="book" hidden>
  <label for="weight">Weight (KG)</label>
  <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight">
</div>
<div class="furniture" hidden>
  <label for="height">Height</label>
  <input type="text" name="height" id="height"><br>
  <label for="width">Width</label>
  <input type="text" name="width" id="width"><br>
  <label for="length">Length</label>
  <input type="text" name="length" id="length"><br>
</div>
```